# Doxygen reference Multiple Parameter Method with @see Tag

Tags: iphone, objective-c, doxygen

I am writing documentation for my iPhone app and I am running into a problem. I want to use a @see tag to reference another method in my documentation but the method has multiple parameters. I have tried including just the method name and the whole method stub but Doxygen doesn't seem it format it. How would reference a method with multiple parameters using the @see tag?

**Method Header (URL.h)**

```
+ (NSMutableString *)generateUrl:(NSString *) url fromParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params;
```

**Doxygen Tag (Failed Attemps)**

```
@see URL#baseUrl
@see URL#generateUrl:(NSString *) url fromParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. It is the method name without any spaces, variable names or variable types like so ....

```
@see URL#generateUrl:fromParams:
```